# DrawImage pixel fidelity checklist

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+, drawimage

I'm using `System.Drawing.Graphics` (a wrapper around GDI+) and several of the various `DrawImage*` functions to composite several images from PNG sources before displaying them in a WinForms C# VS10 designer control.  At one part of the image, what should be sharp, high-contrast pixels drawn at 1:1 from the source images are bleeding into adjacent pixels, creating a blurry effect.

Given the large amount of configurable image transformation that goes on between the source images and the monitor, I know there are a lot of places this could be introduced: DPI scaling, `DrawImage` scaling/filtering modes, mismatched image sizes/formats on my temporary `Bitmap`s,  etc.  And I find my self debugging issues like this repeatedly.

What is the complete set of system settings and APIs that can alter the appearance of images being loaded from a file and displayed onscreen with GDI+ and WinForms?

Comment: What happens if you try using [DrawImageUnscaled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimageunscaled.aspx)?

Comment: @LarsTech: I need to apply a colortransform and alpha-blend with the underlying image.  But the alpha-value is uniform across the image, so it's not variations in alpha causing the bleed.

Comment: @BCoates you could do the colortransform and alpha-blending yourself and still use `DrawImageUnscaled()`. Take a look at http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing.php to see how this can be done faster than using `Bitmap`'s `GetPixel()` and `SetPixel()` methods.

Comment: Maybe you should write a community wiki answer to yourself and write down what you know so far and ask others to fill in what they know?